# Facebook login in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using fb login in my app using below code.

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream" }, -1,
                new DialogListener()
```

this is work correct but if i want to login without auth screen using below code then i am not able to login in fb why

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream" }, 
                new DialogListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite being still listed on their [dev site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/authentication/), the Facebook object and it's associated methods have been [deprecated in version 3.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/)

I would suggest using their Scrumptious tutorial using Fragments for the 'official' way to authenticate: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/

Comment: Thank jeremy for support... i was solved problem using fb version 3.0.